# Wavelets for signal modulation

Tags: time-series, wavelets

How does the Continuous Wavelet Transform handle signal modulation? for instance if an external 8-year period influenced the amplitude of an annual period. i.e. every 8 years the amplitude of the annual cycle grew and shrank periodically.

Would wavelets detect this as an 8 year cycle, or filter the information within the annual domain?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Continous wavelet transform has some support in the Fourier domain that is continously changing with some parameter. In the Fourier domain modulation turns into convolution. So check out the shape of the function you multiply with.

If you don't know the shape of the modulation, then this becomes a problem of *blind deconvolution* you may want to search for. Lots of work has been done on it in many different fields, but it is far too broad to post in just one SE answer.